# Python List Comprehension: Add n specific elements after each element in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to add `n` specific elements after each element in a list using only list comprehension.

Example:

`l = [A, B, C, D, E]`

`element = ''`

for `n = 1` should result in

`l = [A, '', B, '', C, '', D, '', E, '']`

or `n = 2` should result in

`l = [A, '', '', B, '', '', C, '', '', D, '', '', E, '', '']`

Comment: Not related to answer: `list` is a reserved keyword in python. Better change the list's name.

Comment: I don't think you can insert the values using List Comprehension

Comment: @LoukasPap to be pedantic, it is *not* a reserved keyword, which is *why you can use it as a name*. A reserved keyword would be something like `for`, if you tried `for = 0` that would raise a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straight-forward without the List Comprehension.

If you want to use List Comprehension you can do something like:

```
l = ['A','B','C','D','E']

[(x,'') for x in l]
#[('A', ''), ('B', ''), ('C', ''), ('D', ''), ('E', '')]
```

Flatten this nested list by:

```
[item for sublist in ((x,'') for x in l) for item in sublist]
#['A', '', 'B', '', 'C', '', 'D', '', 'E', '']
```

Similarly for two blank spaces:

```
[item for sublist in ((x,'','') for x in l) for item in sublist]
#['A', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', '', '', 'D', '', '', 'E', '', '']
```

---

Edit:

```
n=1
[item for sublist in ([x] + ['']*n for x in l) for item in sublist]
#['A', '', 'B', '', 'C', '', 'D', '', 'E', '']

n=2
#['A', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', '', '', 'D', '', '', 'E', '', '']
```

Comment: If anything, you could save space by just using () for the inner comprehension turning into a generator.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be a more straightforward solution. 
Anyway here is an addition from my side with a variable n: 
[item for sublist in [[x] + ['']*n for x in l] for item in sublist] Maybe we should add this to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use two loops:

```py
def add_n_elements_after_each(iterable, n, padder):
  return [
    padder if i else element
    for element in iterable
      for i in range(0, n + 1)
  ]
```

Try it:

```py
print(add_n_elements_after_each(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 2, ''))

# ['A', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', '', '', 'D', '', '']
```

Comment: He wants with list comprehension.

Comment: @LoukasPap Is what I wrote in my answer not a list comprehension?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use *for* loop for every item in list

```
list_help = []
for l in list:
    list_help.append(l)
    for _ in range(n):
       list_help.append(' ')
```